# IBMMQ push subscription : Is there a way in springboot/quarkuks/other to use push subscription? Not polling

Tags: spring-boot, ibm-mq, quarkus, spring-jms

**Push-subscription**

Is there a way in springboot or quarkus (or other framework) to consume messages from IBMMQ using **push-subscription**. I.e Not polling every minute to see if message exists.

Need not be JMS api.

The DefaultJms... in springboot is polling 1000x times more than the actual messages per day. It is not behaving as ' listener waiting for message push'

Comment: @JoshMc, see updated section in question

Comment: Sorry I had it reversed it is SimpleMessageListenerContainer you want for asynchronous consume.  DefaultMessageListenerContainer does back to back  synchronous gets but you can increase the receive timeout to make it less frequent, see this [blog](https://www.marketaylor.synology.me/?p=668).

Comment: @JoshMc, yes i saw that blog, that's why I was surprised why Default... would work.   I'm going to try Simple .. If it still polls, I'm going to ditch JMS and see if direct mq libraries work in spring. Thanks.

Comment: The IBM MQ classes for Java only support synchronous calls and also have the ability to set a wait time.   You still receive the message just as fast,  it just makes the get call block until either it receives a message or times out based on the wait time (receive timeout in JMS).

Answer (score 0):

You could consume messages from IBM MQ using [vert.x](https://vertx.io/)'s [AMQP client](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-amqp-client/java/). This is a reactive toolkit that will give you an easy way of communicating with IBM MQ using the AMQP channel. Vert.x's AMQP client listens and reacts for push from IBM MQ.

Comment: Q1: Does vertex client poll IBMMQ(bad), or listens and reacts for push from IBMMQ?

Comment: @Espresso see the updated answer

Comment: Is there a vertx, IBMMQ , TLS example?

Comment: @Espresso not that I know of.